# Access Model attribute in scriptlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, scriptlet

I am using Spring MVC, and in my Controller, I am setting a standard model attribute using:

```
...
model.addAttribute("param", value);
...
```

Now, I wish to access this in a scriptlet (within a JSP). For example:

```
<% 
Object value = ***.get***("param"); 
... more java code...
%>
```

How can I do this?

**NOTE**: I understand it is a BAD IDEA to use scriptlets, but please bear with it for now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's stored as a request attribute.

```
Object param = request.getAttribute("param");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I suggest to ask a new question wherein you ask how to achieve the functional requirement without the need to fall back to legacy practices.

Comment: Aah yes, I was trying getParameter() all this while. Thanks, anyways!

Comment: `request.getParameter()` can only return client-supplied HTTP request parameters.